# Add an item to an already existing 2D integer array in a function in windows form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a 2D integer array and i want to add an item in it as per the values i get in the method.

```
  private  int[,]  indexes = new int[100,2];
```

This is the array declared and below is how i add items in the array as per the indexes but in my method i would not know the exact indexes. Is there a way where in i can get the indexes of the last element in the array and than add an element to it or a way where i can add directly at the end of the existing array

```
 indexes[0,0]= currRowIndex;
 indexes[0,1] = 0;
```

Here i have added at the index 0. Similarly i should be able to add to the last index where the elements in an array ends.

Comment: Code you've shown *sets* values of elements of an array, *add* usually means either "increment value" or "increase array length and add new element". Please clarify what you are looking for (and how information provided by search like https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+add+array+element did not help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider of using nested lists - `List<List<int>>` From MSDN [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)
Then new values will be added always to the end of collection

```
List<List<int>> indexes = new List<List<int>>();

indexes.Add(new List<int> { 1, 2 });
```

And retrieve value by index

```
int firstValue = indexes[0][0];
int secondValue = indexes[0][1];
```

Comment: This really helped. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
indexes .GetLength(0)  -> Gets first dimension size

indexes .GetLength(1)  -> Gets second dimension size
```

so you can add items to the list as

```
indexes[indexes .GetLength(0), 
indexes .GetLength(1)] = value;
```

Comment: here what i get is 100 and 2. That i know. I know the length of array as i have declared it. I want to know the index of last element present inside it.